# Can't boot into system or recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot, unbricking, rom

I had the Pixel Experience ROM on `Redmi Note 7 Pro` which got an OTA update and after the update was installed it got stuck on the boot logo of the phone, the usual keys for recovery mode don't work. Reinstalling the recovery through `fastboot flash` and `fastboot boot` gives the same result. Sometimes it shows warning: `Your phone is destroyed press power button to turn off`.

How can I recover from this? [This](https://download.pixelexperience.org/changelog/violet/PixelExperience_caf_violet-9.0-20190710-1613-OFFICIAL.zip) is the ROM that was installed through OTA.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to boot directly into recovery instead of flashing image: `fastboot boot recovery.img`

If it doesn't work, go for flashing factory firmware in `bootloader` or Emergency Download mode. [Here](https://miui.blog/any-devices/install-miui-fastboot-rom/) are the detailed instructions for Xiaomi devices.